# Why does Anne Frank have so many admirers at school?

Tags: dutch-language, anne-frank, the-diary-of-a-young-girl

Anne Frank writes:

> I have a throng of admirers who can't keep their adoring eyes off me
> and who sometimes have to resort to using a broken mirror to try and
> catch a glimpse of me in the classroom

Is this a real event, or was Anne Frank exaggerating?

---

PS: I don't have the exact page number[/not sure how I infer from Kindle], but the date in the diary is "Saturday, 20 June 1942"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The biography by Melissa Muller (Bloomsbury, 1999), based on information from relatives and friends, states that Anne was always popular and assertive at school, and not good at concentrating (which may have meant she was more aware of what the boys were up to). In 1942 there were 12 girls and 18 boys in her class, so the relatively small number of girls could have meant that they all attracted more attention?

Comment: This is a decent starting place for an answer, is there anything else that you can find to support this theory?